# Android display float using settext method

Tags: android, textview, floating

iam allmoust done with my app but iam stuck on this thing , i have two int's
called "positive" and "negative" and when i procces source below it shows 0.0

```
 total = positive + negative;
     float rate = positive/total;
     rate*=100;
     TextView analitycs = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.app_scores_analitycs);
     analitycs.setText(String.valueOf(rate));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Victor said is true.

Also you might want to use something different than `String.valueOf(rate)` to set the text of your text view, because this method can give you an ugly representation of the number.

You should probably use `String.format("%.2f", rate)` ad tweak that to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Are positive and total floats/doubles?

If not, then an int/int will give you an int.

The solution would be to cast either positive or negative as a float.

try the following:

```
float rate = ((float)(positive))/total;
```